# Replacing string in textfile with quotes and doublequotes with sed

Tags: string, unix, replace, sed, quotes

Lets say I want to replace the following string within a textfile:

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + \ + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

I came up with this sed command, but surprisingly nothing happens at all.

```
sed -i "s/document.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src=\"\' + \\ + \"google-analytics.com\/ga.js\' type=\'text\/javascript\'%3E%3C\/script%3E\"));//g" myfile.html
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Backslashes should be doubly escaped, since they are expanded by both `sed` and the shell. Use `\\\\` (becomes `\\` in the shell, then `\` in `sed`)
2. You're matching on `src="'`, but your file contains `src='"`.

Use

```
sed -i \
"s|document.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src='\" + \\\\ + \"google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E\"));||g" \
myfile.html
```

I've replaced `/` with `|` to make it more readable (no more need to escape `/`).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the trick with the pipe. However, shouldn't this one work, too?

    "s/document.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src='\" + \\\\ + \"google-analytics.com\/ga.js' type='text\/javascript'%3E%3C\/script%3E\"));//g"

Comment: Should work, but I decided on pipes before further editing your command. It doesn't only work with `|` by the way, other characters are possible (see the `sed` manual).